# How do I implement function in this program to validate or invalidate the account number?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code so far.A list called current_accts should validate all the account.Verifying the account number entered should be done in a function called check_account() that will accept the account entered by the user and also the list current_accts. This function should return a 1 if the account is valid otherwise return 0 if the account is not valid. Can anyone help me put in the functions?

```
accNum = int(input("Please enter your seven digit account number: "))   
if accNum == 5679035:
     print 'Account', accNum,'is valid'
elif accNum ==  8232322:
     print 'Account', accNum,'is valid'
elif accNum == 2134988:
     print 'Account', accNum,'is valid'
elif accNum == 6541234:
     print 'Account', accNum,'is valid'
elif accNum == 3984591:
     print 'Account', accNum,'is valid'
elif accNum == 1298345:
     print 'Account', accNum, 'is valid'
elif accNum == 7849123:
     print'Account', accNum, 'is valid'
elif accNum == 8723217:
     print'Account', accNum, 'is valid'
else:
     print "Account", accNum, "is NOT valid"
```

Answer (score 2):

its pretty simple in python to implement.

```
valid_account_list = [1,2,3,4]
input_account = 4 # user input
def validate_account(input_account ,valid_account_list)
    if input_account in valid_account_list:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic way

```
def validate_account(input_account, valid_account_list):
    return 1 if input_account in valid_account_list else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of code you want:

```
try:
  def check_account(accNum):
     current_acts=[5679035,8232322,2134988,6541234,3984591,1298345,7849123,8723217]
     return accNum in current_acts

  accNum = int(input("Please enter your seven digit account number: "))
  is_valid_account = check_account(accNum)
  if is_valid_account:
     print 'The digit account number ' + str(accNum) + ' is valid.'
  else:
     print 'The digit accoutn number ' + str(accNum) + ' is not valid.'


except ValueError:
   #the input is not a valid number
   print "You should add a vaild digit account number"
```